# How do I escape a room without a pickaxe?

Tags: terraria

I have gone through many battles, slain countless enemies, farmed bosses, and gotten to hardmode. Now I'm faced with my greatest challenge...

A square room.

I have somehow thrown my only pickaxe through a wall and trapped myself. I have my door blocked off with bricks, and I don't have any explosives in my inventory. I have a bed in here with me (which my spawn is set to) and no pick to mine it up to spawn outside of my room. I can't craft a pickaxe or anvil because my iron and anvil are in another house.

So here is the list of things I have access to:

- a [Dye Trader](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dye_Trader)
- a full set of [Crimson armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimson_armor) and accessories
- a [Pwnhammer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pwnhammer)
- 3 [Goodie Bags](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goodie_Bag)
- [Torches](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Torch), Ultrabright Torches, and [Glowsticks](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Glowstick)
- [Dirt Blocks](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dirt_Block) and other common building items
- a [Work Bench](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Work_Bench)
- a [Campfire](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Campfire)
- an empty [Chest](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Chest)
- 50 Gold [Coins](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Coins)

How can I escape this room?

Comment: Assigning the demo man to live in the house might work. I can't test it, but he might teleport if you relog.

Comment: @acbabis the merchant sells a copper pickaxe. It would be cheaper and less dangerous.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest solution I can see off-hand is to go to another world:

1. Save and exit the trap world.
2. Go into a different, second world.
3. Make a pickaxe, get a bomb, etc.
4. Save and exit this second world.
5. Return to your trap world.
6. Use your item to make your way out.

Comment: Seems unnecessary given that the inventory itself carries over between worlds anyway. Just make the pickaxe in another world and put it in your inventory.

Comment: Fair point. I don't play in multiple worlds so this was just based on a quick search result which fit the desired effect. I will update the answer.

Comment: I can't get any metal without a pick, which I don't have. getting a bomb through a pot could work, but I solved my own problem.

Answer (score 12):

I solved my own problem by breaking the torches so it was invalid housing, then saving and exiting. I did end up losing my pick (not that big of a deal).

I hope this solves any future problems.

Comment: Invalidating the housing so that your spawn changes is clever. The only potential failing is if your default spawn is inside the trap and you have no other spawns in that world to fall back to. Other than having someone else jump into your game, you'd likely lose instanced items like the pick you dropped in pretty much all solutions.

Comment: @skovacs1 If that happened I would start a new character and use the copper pick to break the wood surrounding the house. Should I update my answer to include this?

Comment: I don't see the need, but if you feel it improves your answer, go right ahead. Having a second character with the proper item enter the game is a fine solution. Questions can have multiple correct answers and accepting an answer marks that answer as best, but does not mark other answers as incorrect. I personally like the simplicity and elegance of your answer.

Comment: @skovacs1 I will leave the answer as it is now. If they really had that problem they would check the comments right...?

Answer (score 1):

1.3 would have solved this problem, since you can now right-click a bed to remove your spawn point if it's set there. You could have also used the dirt and the hammer to make a simple hoik to glitch through the wall. Those were the first two things that came to mind.

(Sorry for necroposting)

Answer (score -4):

mine the walls with the pwnhammer, make them into wood and turn the wood into a picaxe

Comment: What if the walls arent made of wood?

Comment: What if the box Is made of aomething wood can't mine?

Comment: Besides, you need an anvul, which he doesnt have